# error occur when saving image to local path

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, resize

I get an image file, re-size it and then save with a different name in the same folder (  filename+"-resize" ), but I get this error

```
A generic error occurred in GDI+
```

Here is my code for resizing method ,

```
private  string resizeImageAndSave(string imagePath)
{
    System.Drawing.Image fullSizeImg
         = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(imagePath));
    var thumbnailImg = new Bitmap(565, 290);
    var thumbGraph = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnailImg);
    thumbGraph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    thumbGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    thumbGraph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    var imageRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 565, 290);
    thumbGraph.DrawImage(fullSizeImg, imageRectangle);
    string targetPath = imagePath.Replace(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imagePath),     Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imagePath) + "-resize");
    thumbnailImg.Save(targetPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg); //(A generic error occurred in GDI+) Error occur here !
    thumbnailImg.Dispose();
    return targetPath;
}
```

I want to know how to fix it ?

Comment: http://imageresizing.net/docs/best-practices I don't know how to fix it but I think the link could interest you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others said, it could be a permission problem or the directory might not exist.
However, you could try cloning the image before saving it. This could fix the issue if the above is not the problem.

```
private static string resizeImageAndSave(string imagePath)
{
    System.Drawing.Image fullSizeImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(imagePath));
    var thumbnailImg = new Bitmap(565, 290);
    var thumbGraph = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnailImg);
    thumbGraph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    thumbGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    thumbGraph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    var imageRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 565, 290);
    thumbGraph.DrawImage(fullSizeImg, imageRectangle);
    fullSizeImg.Dispose(); //Dispose of the original image
    string targetPath = imagePath.Replace(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imagePath), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imagePath) + "-resize");
    Bitmap temp = thumbnailImg.Clone() as Bitmap; //Cloning
    thumbnailImg.Dispose();
    temp.Save(targetPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg); 
    temp.Dispose();
    return targetPath;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

After this line of code...

```
string targetPath = imagePath.Replace(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imagePath),     Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imagePath) + "-resize");
```

Try this please...add image name with extension

```
if (!Directory.Exists(targetPath))
   Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
//now do the rest and place image name and extension...
thumbnailImg.Save(targetPath + @"\img.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg); 
thumbnailImg.Dispose();
return targetPath;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a permission problem.

Change the Permissions on your destination folder so that ASP.NET can write to that.

Remember that the user that save the file is not you but ASP.NET user.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check your permisson to write files since I can't find any big issues from your code.

Answer (score 1):

Please check what is the path that is being constructed, you can use below before save to ensure that your directory path exists:-

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName));
```

Also consider issue lock held on source file, so you can create a copy and dispose existing reference:-

```
var thumbnailImgNew = new Bitmap(thumbnailImg);
thumbnailImg.Dispose(); 
thumbnailImg=null;
//Save it to target path
thumbnailImgNew.Save(targetPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done some changes and this code is working fine:(You have to first upload the file to your website before re-sizing. after re-sizing you can delete the original file)
Step1: I have copied Image to my application.
Step2: On button click event I have retrieved the image path and supplied to re-size function.

```
private string resizeImageAndSave(string imagePath)
    {
        System.Drawing.Image fullSizeImg
             = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imagePath);
        var thumbnailImg = new Bitmap(565, 290);
        var thumbGraph = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnailImg);
        thumbGraph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        thumbGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        thumbGraph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        var imageRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 565, 290);
        thumbGraph.DrawImage(fullSizeImg, imageRectangle);
        string targetPath = imagePath.Replace(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imagePath), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imagePath) + "-resize");
        thumbnailImg.Save(targetPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg); //(A generic error occurred in GDI+) Error occur here !
        thumbnailImg.Dispose();
        return targetPath;
    }
    protected void bntUploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string file = Server.MapPath("tree.jpg");
        resizeImageAndSave(file);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
    private string resizeImageAndSave(byte[] imageBytes, string fileName) {
        var mem = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
        System.Drawing.Image fullSizeImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(mem);

        var thumbnailImg = new Bitmap(565, 290);
        var thumbGraph = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnailImg);
        thumbGraph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        thumbGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        thumbGraph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        var imageRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 565, 290);
        thumbGraph.DrawImage(fullSizeImg, imageRectangle);

        string targetPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) + "-resize.jpg");

        thumbnailImg.Save(targetPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg); //(A generic error occurred in GDI+) Error occur here !
        thumbnailImg.Dispose();

        return targetPath;
    }

    protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var inStream = Request.Files[0].InputStream;
        var buff = new byte[inStream.Length];

        inStream.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);

        resizeImageAndSave(buff, Request.Files[0].FileName);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that link can help you

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23011/Simple-Image-Resizing-Library

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in location, problem is in resizing.

Problem with GDI can happen when resizing, croping image.
Make sure that your image will be 100% size of rectangle or crop your image to desired size and then resize it.

So if you have image 800x600 and you want to resize it to 450x339 you will have one empty pixel and it can cause error in GDI+, so what I'm suggesting you is to make sure that your image when resized will have correct size. So if this can help you I have created class that helps me to resize and crop image.

```
public class ImageHandler
{
    private Image cropImage(Image img, Rectangle cropArea)
    {
        Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(img);
        if (bmpImage.Size.Width < cropArea.Width)
            cropArea.Width = bmpImage.Size.Width;
        if (bmpImage.Size.Height < cropArea.Height)
            cropArea.Height = bmpImage.Size.Height;
        Bitmap bmpCrop = bmpImage.Clone(cropArea,
                                        bmpImage.PixelFormat);
        return (Image)(bmpCrop);
    }

    private Image resizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
    {
        int sourceWidth = imgToResize.Width;
        int sourceHeight = imgToResize.Height;

        float nPercent = 0;
        float nPercentW = 0;
        float nPercentH = 0;

        nPercentW = ((float)size.Width / (float)sourceWidth);
        nPercentH = ((float)size.Height / (float)sourceHeight);

        if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
            nPercent = nPercentH;
        else
            nPercent = nPercentW;

        int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
        int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b);
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight);
        g.Dispose();

        return (Image)b;
    }
    public Image ResizeWithCrop(Image imgToResize, Size size, bool center = true)
    {
        int sourceWidth = imgToResize.Width;
        int sourceHeight = imgToResize.Height;

        float nPercent = 0;
        float nPercentW = 0;
        float nPercentH = 0;

        nPercentW = ((float)size.Width / (float)sourceWidth);
        nPercentH = ((float)size.Height / (float)sourceHeight);

        if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
            nPercent = nPercentW;
        else
            nPercent = nPercentH;
        float resultWidth = sourceWidth * nPercent;
        float resultHeight = sourceHeight * nPercent;
        int destWidth = (int)resultWidth;
        int destHeight = (int)resultHeight;
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b);
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight);
        g.Dispose();
        int restWidth = destWidth - size.Width;
        int restHeight = destHeight - size.Height;

        int pX = center ? restWidth > 0 ? (int)(restWidth / 2) : 0 : 0;
        int pY = center ? restHeight > 0 ? (int)(restHeight / 2) : 0 : 0;
        return cropImage((Image)b, new Rectangle(pX, pY, size.Width, size.Height));


    }
    public void SaveJpeg(string path, Image img, long quality = 85L)
    {
        try
        {


        EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);

        ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = getEncoderInfo(@"image/jpeg");

        EncoderParameters encoderParams
        = new EncoderParameters(1);

        encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;

        System.IO.MemoryStream mss = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

        System.IO.FileStream fs
        = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Create
        , System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite);

        img.Save(mss, jpegCodec, encoderParams);
        byte[] matriz = mss.ToArray();
        fs.Write(matriz, 0, matriz.Length);

        mss.Close();
        fs.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    private ImageCodecInfo getEncoderInfo(string mimeType)
    {
        // Get image codecs for all image formats
        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();

        // Find the correct image codec
        for (int i = 0; i < codecs.Length; i++)
            if (codecs[i].MimeType == mimeType)
                return codecs[i];
        return null;
    }

    public void SavePng(string path, Image img, long quality = 85L)
    {
        try
        {
            EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, quality);

            ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = getEncoderInfo(@"image/png");

            EncoderParameters encoderParams
            = new EncoderParameters(1);

            encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;

            System.IO.MemoryStream mss = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

            System.IO.FileStream fs
            = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Create
            , System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite);

            img.Save(mss, jpegCodec, encoderParams);
            byte[] matriz = mss.ToArray();
            fs.Write(matriz, 0, matriz.Length);

            mss.Close();
            fs.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

About this line:

```
string targetPath = imagePath.Replace(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imagePath),     Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imagePath) + "-resize");
```

Are you sure that the file name without extension is not present many times in the original imagePath ? That could cause problems, like not targeting the right folder.